# error about get data

Tags: python, odoo

i have a function :

```
def tong_thoigian (self,cr,uid,ids,context={}):
                obj=self.browse(cr,uid,ids,context=context)[0]
                cr.execute('''select name,giolam from x_giolam where name=%s'''%(obj.ma_luong))
                kq=cr.fetchall()
                tong=0.00000
                for i in kq:
                      tong+=kq[1]                          
                self.write(cr,uid,ids,{'tonggiolam':tong},context=context)
```

and this is table x_giolam:

```
class x_giolam(osv.osv):
    _name = 'x_giolam'
    _description = 'Gio Lam'
    _columns = {
                        'name': fields.integer('Lọai',size=64,required="true"),
                        'giolam' : fields.float('Gio lam',size=64,required="True"),
                        'time_in': fields.char('Gio vào',size=20),
                        'time_out' :fields.char('Gio về',size=20),
                        'congviec' :fields.char('Cong viec',size=50),
    }   
x_giolam()
```

and the 'self' is table x_salary, i think isn't importance to say about it because i want write a function for sum salary of a staff when name=Ma_luong of table x_salary
and the error is

```
IndexError: list index out of range
```

the type of Giolam is float...
and i write with in openerp
and i think error in line 'tong+=kq[1]'
How can i fix it  ? 
thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using my magic crystal ball, I'm guessing that `cr.execute` is a call to the standard database API. So `kr.fetchall()` will return a tuple of rows. However, it seems that your SQL is returning only a single row.

You probably mean `tong += kq[0][1]`, ie the second column (`giolam`) of the first row of the result. Alternatively, use `kr.fetchone()` to just get a single row, then you can keep it as `kq[1]`. Either way, you should check that your db call actually returns results.

Comment: and sorry you can help me one more time... in table x_giolam so many row and i want to sum all it with key is'name=ma_luong' i can't do it
Thanks!